# Does Fibonacci anyon come from a representation category of Hopf algebra?

Tags: mathematical-physics, topological-field-theory, topological-order, anyons, category-theory

I have heard that the UMTC(unitary modular tensor category) of Fibonacci anyon comes from a quantum group, but the representation category of Hopf algebra is equipped with a forgetful functor to $\textrm{Vect}$. Note that fibonacci can't have a forgetful functor to $\textrm{Vect}$, because if we map the nontrivial simple object $\tau$ to a vector space of dimension $n$, then $\tau\otimes\tau=1\oplus\tau$ implies $n^2=n+1$ which has no solution.

My question is whether my argument is correct? If it is correct, then the UMTC of fibonacci must come from a quantum group in other sense, what is it?